# ¿Cómo saber cuántas mayúsculas, minúsculas y números tiene un string?

Tags: python, string

Tengo que crear un cogido en Python donde yo coloque una frase y me diga cuántas  mayúsculas, minúsculas y números tiene la frase.

Por ejemplo, dado este texto:

```
ejemPLO35
```

Devolvería en formato "minúsculas-mayúsculas-números":

```
432
```

Este es el código que he implementado:

```
casos= int(raw_input())

def contar(x): 
    may, minu, num = 0,0,0 
    return(may,minu,num)

ord(may= range(65,90) 

for i in range(casos): 
    palabra = raw_input() 
    print(contar(palabra))
```

Comment: Buenas. Podrías añadir lo que has intentado? Cuales son tus errores?

Comment: casos= int(raw_input())

def contar(x):
     may, minu, num = 0,0,0
     return(may,minu,num)
ord(may= range(65,90)
for i in range(casos):
      palabra = raw_input()
      print(contar(palabra))



ahi voy, es con la tabla ascii

Comment: Deberias añadir el codigo a la pregunta, no en los comentarios. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b no conozco de python, por lo que te pido tu opinión, ¿el código que colocó el OP está completo? si es así, te animo a que edites la pregunta y reportes el comentario como _obsoleto_ para ser eliminado.

Comment: Hola Jordan, si alguna respuesta te ha servido, recuerda marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Usando "comprensión de listas":

```
mayusculas = len([c for c in texto if c.isupper()])
minusculas = len([c for c in texto if c.islower()])
numeros = len([c for c in texto if c.isdigit()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se me ocurre es usar [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)

Con la funcion `sub()` le paso como primer parametro lo que quiero que quite del `string` y lo sustituya por el 2ndo parametro.

La expresion `[^A-Z]` busca todas las coincidencias que no sean Mayusculas. 
Lo mismo para las minusculas y para numeros `[^\d]`. Luego uso `len()` para que devuelva la longitud de cada variable.

```
import re

texto = "Texto Con Mayusculas y minusculas y num2344"

textoSoloMayusculas = re.sub('[^A-Z]', '', texto)

textoSoloMinusculas = re.sub('[^a-z]', '', texto)

textoSoloNumeros = re.sub('[^\d]', '', texto)

print "Mayusculas: " + str(len(textoSoloMayusculas));

print "Minusculas: " + str(len(textoSoloMinusculas));

print "Numeros: " + str(len(textoSoloNumeros));
```

Resultado:

```
sh-4.3$ python main.py 
Mayusculas: 3  
Minusculas: 30  
Numeros: 4
```